# Is there a way to demonstrate a message has been edited using Outlook's "Edit Message" (or its subject)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, forensics

Is there any way (complicated or no) to demonstrate that an Outlook message has been edited using the 'Edit Message' function, or that the subject was edited on its own?

For purposes of this answer, I would preferably be interested in not only methods available to an end-user, but for curiousity's sake would also be interested in methods available to an IT department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **View** tab, turn off the **Reading Pane**.
[Reading Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1lO4.png)

In the **Arrangement** ribbon, click **Add Columns**, under the Select available columns from, click the drop-down box and choose **All mail fileds**, find **modified** in the drop-down box and add it to the view to display.
[Add Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HdCP.png)

When the steps has been perfomed, you can clearly see the modified time is different from the received time.
[modified time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRv9k.png)

Hope the above can help you!